# Difference between master and gcloud branch

Tags: git, gcloud

After pushing my local code using GIT to the google APP Engine. The master branch is update. My gcloud branch still has the old version. How do I merge the branches?

Comment: How to merge two branches : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following command:
`git rebase master gcloud`

Comment: I have an fatal exception: no such branch: gcloud. Even though I have the branch in my google console

Comment: @Samualkrish, you should use `git checkout --track origin/gcloud` to create a local copy of remote branch and then run `git rebase master gcloud` to update local gcloud branch. After updated local gcloud branch, run `git push` to update your remote branch.

Comment: Thanks for your help